# Response row size overflow (9804) error

Tags: teradata

i am executing below query in teradata 14.0

```
        SELECT oreplace(CAST(RULE_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') RULE_ID,
        oreplace(CAST(PHASE_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') PHASE_ID,
        oreplace(CAST(TARGET_TABLE_NAME AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') TARGET_TABLE_NAME,
        oreplace(CAST(AUDIT_TABLE_NAME AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') AUDIT_TABLE_NAME,
        oreplace(CAST(PROC_NAME AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') PROC_NAME,
        oreplace(CAST(ACTIVE_START_DT AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') ACTIVE_START_DT,
        oreplace(CAST(ACTIVE_END_DT AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') ACTIVE_END_DT,
        oreplace(CAST(ACTIVE_IND AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','')  ACTIVE_IND,
        oreplace(CAST(WRITE_AUDIT_IND AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') WRITE_AUDIT_IND,
        oreplace(CAST(SCENARIO_TYPE AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') SCENARIO_TYPE,
        oreplace(CAST(RULE_ORDER AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') RULE_ORDER

        FROM table
```

When i execute this query, 9804 (response row size overflow) is received.

Charaterset used : ASCII

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resulting datatype of `oReplace` is a `VarChar(8000)` you must CAST the result of the function, not the parameter:

```
 CAST(oreplace(PROC_NAME,' ','') AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS PROC_NAME,
```

But why do you want to remove *all* spaces? If there are trailing spaces you can simply `TRIM` them.

Comment: proc_name is an integer column , so oreplace gives an error.that's why i have casted it first.
i need to remove all spaces within the data of all columns

Comment: @anurag: There's no white space in an INTEGER unless you CAST it as a CHAR (and this would be stupid if you don't want white space)

Comment: i am duing a minus check between two views and i am creating minus queries at run time , through VBA, as i posted in my question.so this is the pain point, where i am not able to identify the datatype of column at run time so i can put oreplace function on specific columns only.

Comment: @anurag:You didn't specify MINUS/VBA in your questions. But if you have to compare two views they should have comparable output.

Comment: one view is like -
    Column A,ColumnB
     a b c d,1 2 3 4
and another is like-
   Column A,ColumnB
   abcd,1234
Thats why i have to write oreplace for all varchar columns in view.

Comment: @anurag: You could add another CAST on the OREPLACE: `cast(oreplace(CAST(PHASE_ID AS VARCHAR(1000)),' ','') as varchar(1000))`Are you sure you want `abc  def` being equal to `ab  cd ef`?

Comment: thank you so much for helping out so quick. Cast function over replace did the trick.
You are a saviour man :) +1 for you answer.